# Could not find appcompat-v7.jar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

All the while my apps running smoothly with this `build.gradle` file.
Then, I need to display TreeView so I have to use third party library from [bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView).

When I add `compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'`into the `build.gradle` file, it showed this error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not find appcompat-v7.jar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.1.1/appcompat-v7-24.1.1.jar

This is the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ada.foresight"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabled multidex support
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    // problem occur while I added this line:
    //compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'       
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Try updating google's dependencies to the newest version possible (currently for v7 it's 25.0.1), as well as the Build Tools.

Comment: @PrzemyslawJablonski You are correct! It's version and Build Tool problem! I changed to newest (v7 25.0.1 version) for both dependencies and Build Tools! Thanks!